# How to summon tnt to a specific player’s location

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was thinking of trolling my friend in our survival world. Essentially, I’d like to be able to press a button on a command block that will summon tnt or spawn a mob at his location. I know how to spawn a mob or tnt, but I don’t know how to locate him. I’d tell you what I’ve tried, but to be perfectly honest I have no idea where to start. If anyone knows the command it would be greatly appreciated! (I play on Bedrock 1.16 in case that matters.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your command block:

```
execute <player> ~ ~ ~ summon <entity>
```

Whatever the player's name is, put that on `<player>`, and summon any `<entity>` given in the command.

You can try something else, however. Changing the coordinates where the player is standing by `y + 75` will make it look like they nearly got nuked.

Simply:

```
execute <player> ~ ~75 ~ summon tnt
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works for 1.16, the updated syntax for 1.20+ version is:

```
/execute at <player> run summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```